# How to Generate GeoJSON file for a Country on Google MAP in Android

Tags: android, ios, dictionary, kotlin, geojson

I'm trying to highlight or create a polygon over whole country,
but I want to create different countries GeoJSON file

Help me out from where i can get file or create it.

[image: GEO JSON file]

Answer (score 0):

There is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson and https://github.com/cocoahero/android-geojson , just google it